# Flask & AJAX - Reloading a new page with variables

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

- I have an index.html page that asks for a 'user_id' and then passes it back to flask using Ajax
- Flask uses the 'user_id' to call a couple of python functions that write to MySQL, and then return a number of variables (session_uuid, user_id etc...)
- I want to load an entirely new page with those variables - The response I get is valid, but my browser doesn't load the page

**Question:** Why is browser not moving to home.html from index.html?

**Python**

```
n_left = 0
n_right = 1


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    data = request.get_json()
    data_user_id = data['user_id']

    user_id, session_uuid = user_id_session(data_user_id)

    session_uuid, user_id, img_left, img_right, dt_start = user_id_session_url(user_id, session_uuid, n_left, n_right)

    return render_template('home.html', session_uuid=session_uuid, user_id=user_id, img_left=img_left, img_right=img_right, dt_start=dt_start)
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn').on('click', function () {

        var user_id = $('#user_id_input').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({user_id: user_id}),
            success: function() {
                window.location = 'home.html';

            }
        });

    });

});
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Start</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <input type='hidden' id='session_uuid' value="{{session_uuid}}">
    <input type='hidden' id='user_id' value="{{user_id}}">
    <input type='hidden' id='dt_start' value="{{dt_start}}">
    <img class='image' src="{{img_left}}" id='left' width="40%">
    <img class='image' src="{{img_right}}" id='right' width="40%">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened with me also, request.json() returned none to me.
inspect the webpage in your brower and see if there is an error in console.

in place of this

```
data = request.get_json()
data_user_id = data['user_id']
```

try with this

```
data_user_id = request.form.get("user_id")
```

Edit:
You should not send ajax request if you want to reload page because ajax is used for getting data without reloading.

You can use form tag in your index.html

```
<form action="/home" method="post">....</form>
```

And get data using `request.form.get("name_of_input")`

Comment: no I can get the data, the issue is that despite the fact I see the response, my browser stays on the original page as opposed to routing to the new page with all the variables. :(

Comment: Don't use ajax , use form tag and you need to add name attribute the input tag by which they can be accessed.

Comment: You can select this as right answer if you want.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: there will be a tick left of my answer click it. see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)